# A Guide on Command Line MonoGame

Tags: c#, .net-core, monogame, .net-framework-version

Anyone want a guide on using MonoGame with the command line? I have been very reliant on the MonoGame community recently and I’ve just had a bit of a breakthrough so wanted to note down my learnings in case it helps someone else. I'll answer my own question to give it...

Answer (score -2):

I have been very reliant on Visual Studio for MonoGame, and recently I switched to Linux so had to find an alternative. I found that alternative in Rider, but I wanted to go one step further and release myself from my dependence on an IDE. I wanted the freedom to code anywhere and a greater understanding of what was going on under the hood with .NET. So I managed to rebuild my game using the command line to produce the simplest, cleanest setup possible for a game that utilises a shared engine library and things like shaders. I achieved this today and it took so much research that I thought I’d try and write a guide to help others avoid the pain!

So here it is - a guide on how to work with MonoGame outside of an IDE. I hope it’s of use to someone.

https://www.ladesoft.com/pages/notes/monogame_command_line.html

Comment: Link only spam-like post. Please review help on what answers should and should not have.

Comment: I think it's a little unfair to class it as spam, I'm trying to share knowledge on a subject that isn't widely covered. Stack Overflow even says that that's a good thing to do.

Comment: Self-answerring your questions for extra knowledge on the site is encouraged. But the problem is that you're basically advertising an off-site guide. If this guide is self-written. Then I think you'll be fine placing the contents of the guide as answer here. (See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: That's fair enough, I guess I just didn't see the point in copying the entire thing over. It wasn't intended as promotion in any way, but purely meant in the spirit of sharing.